# Running Jenkins in docker with custom uid / gid

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:latest
```

I'm build a Jenkins container as follows:

```
docker build -t my-jenkins --build-arg uid=1003 --build-arg gid=1003 .
```

I then run the image as follows:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 my-jenkins
```

I go to `localhost:8080` and finish installation (without any plugins selected).

I then create a job with a single shell command:

```
id
```

I run the job and I expect the output of the job to be

```
+ id
uid=1003(jenkins) gid=1003(jenkins) groups=1003(jenkins)
```

The output however, is

```
+ id
uid=1000(jenkins) gid=1000(jenkins) groups=1000(jenkins)
```

which seems to indicate that my `--build-arg`s for `uid` and `gid` are **completely ignored**.

Why is this? The Jenkins Dockerfile [should accept uid/gid as guild args](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile).

Answer (score 1):

As usual I think I came up with the answers shortly after spelling out the problem carefully here. I would be great if someone could confirm that my understanding is correct.

---

### TL;DR: It's not possible to use `--build-arg` for `FROM` images

The `FROM` command basically tells docker what binary image to start from. The `FROM` image is not built recursively. This obviously means that `--build-arg` won't be taken into account in the `FROM` image.

### So why is `uid` and `gid` even `ARG`s in the first place if I can't use them?

It *is* possible to use them in a reasonable straight forward way. `docker build` accepts git repo URLs when building, so you can indeed kick off a Jenkins docker with custom `uid` and `gid` quite easily as follows:

```
docker build -t my-jenkins --build-arg uid=1003 --build-arg gid=1003 https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker.git
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --rm my-jenkins
```

### But I need to create my own `Dockerfile` :-(

If you really need to custobmize the Jenkins image *and* need a custom uid / gid, the best way forward is to change the uid / gid of the Jenkins user in your Dockerfile. The uid = 1000 and gid = 1000 is already hardwired when your part of the Dockerfile kicks in.